# Neomutt binding questions for unread emails and sidebar navigation

Tags: linux, neomutt

I'm working on setting up neomutt for the first time and have hit a couple of stumbling blocks with key bindings, and wanted to confirm if I was doing something wrong or if what I'm looking to do isn't possible.

### Sidebar navigation

I've currently navigate emails using the up and down arrow keys, and the sidebar using the below commands I'd like to make things a little easier in my neomutt config, and change my sidebar navigation keys to be `ctrl+Up` and `ctrl+Down`. I've tried to use `\C<Up>`, `\C<\Up\>` and other variations but none seem to work.:

```
bind index,pager \Cp sidebar-prev       # Ctrl-p - Previous Mailbox

bind index,pager \Cl sidebar-next       # Ctrl-l - Next Mailbox

bind index,pager \Co sidebar-open       # Ctrl-o - Open Highlighted Mailbox
```

I'd like to make things a little easier in my neomutt config, and change my sidebar navigation keys to be `ctrl+Up` and `ctrl+Down`. I've tried to use `\C<Up>`, `\C<\Up\>` and other variations but none seem to work.

Does anyone know if this is possible/ how I should write the syntax, or is this not possible?

### Email Flagging: Unread

Whenever I get a new email in, it is flagged with an `O` to indicate the email is currently unread. I'm trying to find out how I can mark an email unread even after I've read it (as I intend to use the 'toggle-read` option to filter out what I still need to action. I've had a look through the [neomutt site](https://neomutt.org/) for key terms like flagging but I can't seem to find the correct thing I'm looking for. That or perhaps I misunderstood the wording on the page.

Does anyone know if there is a keybinding to do this or if they can share which page on this site covers what I am looking to do, so I can review it?

Appreciate any help that can be offered here.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to the answer to the first question via a bug post - https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla//show_bug.cgi?id=213212

I found the below commands to work for me:

```
bind index,pager <C-Up> sidebar-prev            # Ctrl-Up Arrow - Previous Mailbox
bind index,pager <C-Down> sidebar-next          # Ctrl-Down Arrow - Next Mailbox
bind index,pager <C-Right> sidebar-open         # Ctrl-Right Arrow - Open Highlighted Mailbox
```

One can also use `<S-Up>` should they want to use Shift+Up for navigation. It seems `<C-S-Up>` isn't a thing that works for Ctrl+Shift+Up, but I'll update the post if I figure that out.